# How to generate VS proj with both 32-bit and 64-bit configurations using CMake

Tags: visual-studio, 64-bit, cmake

Does any one know how to generate a VS proj/soln file with both 32-bit and 64-bit configurations using CMake.

Comment: A good feature request.

Comment: Any changes for 3.XX versions?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can't. With CMake you can generate separate solution files for 32-bit and 64-bit depending on the [Visual Studio generator](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#section_Generators) option you specify upon invoking CMake.

Comment: For some reason i cannot find the Win64 corresponding option as part of my CMake generators. I have a 64bit machine with Visual studio 10 installed. any idea?

Comment: Are you using the Express Edition? This one does not support 64-bit compilation.

Comment: "Visual Studio 11 Win64" would be for 64bit, ""Visual Studio 11" for 32bit (=Visual Studio 2012)

Comment: This is ridiculous as it kills nature of build configurations in Visual studio, and should be corrected.